# how to read multiple resources using spring annotations

Tags: java, spring

I have the following context.xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
          ">
  <context:annotation-config />
  <bean id="MyPropertyHolderConfig"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
      <list>
        <!-- Note: The 'server.config.override.location' variable is setup during start of the Virgo Server -->
        <value>file:#{systemProperties['con.file.pathtoFile']}/myservice-service.properties</value>
        <value>file:#{systemProperties['con.file.pathtoFile']}/myservice-mynotes.txt</value>
        <value>classpath:myservice-service.properties</value>
         <value>classpath:myservice-mynotes.txt</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

I am able to access the properties from .properties file using the following for accessing value of a key in it.

```
@Value("${myfile.path}")
private static String myfile.path;
```

But I don't know how to access the other resource "myservice-mynotes.txt" from the context. Basically  I want to get the path of this "myservice-mynotes.txt" file in my program and then read it in my program.

For example: here I need to get the mynotesFilePath using annotations and then pass this string to a method which accepts the path to the file.

```java
Stirng mynotesFilePath = "C:/test/myservice-mynotes.txt";
```

and then

```java
File f = new File(mynotesFilePath);
```

Please help.

Comment: yes Keith, that is correct

Comment: is there supposed to be a "c" at the end of <value>classpath:myservice-mynotes.txtc</value> in the last value line?

Comment: Why not put the path of the txt file in the properties file and set another @value?

Comment: because we do not want to hard code the path of the txt file in properties file.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bit of confusion here.

PropertyPLaceholderConfigurer reads and propagates properties to your beans.

If you don't need properties and their values but instead want to get some file location you are talking about Resource, which can be obtained using context,
see:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html